# React setState of an object returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, iot

So I have this react app made for a IoT project that as 3 charts with temperature and humity of soil and air, I make a fetch to my API witch returns a response JSON similar to this(But with 10 data values, I didn't include all to not make this post huge):

```
{
  "dados":[
{
  "T_air":20,
  "H_air":60,
  "soil":70,
  "Time":"2019-12-12T16:09:35.719Z"
},
{
  "T_air":20,
  "H_air":60,
  "soil":70,
  "Time":"2019-12-12T16:09:35.719Z"
},
{
  "T_air":20,
  "H_air":60,
  "soil":70,
  "Time":"2019-12-12T16:09:35.719Z"
},
{
  "T_air":20,
  "H_air":60,
  "soil":70,
  "Time":"2019-12-12T16:09:35.719Z"
},
{
  "T_air":20,
  "H_air":60,
  "soil":70,
  "Time":"2019-12-12T16:09:35.719Z"
}
],
  "LastTime":"12/12/2019, 15:43:53"
}
```

The point is I need to print the `LastTime` object in the render, for that I use the `setState` property but if console.log the ResData I can see my object, however if I console.log `results` It says undefined.
You can see in my code that if I use `ResData.dados[i].T_air` it gives no problem at all, so It's not the API fault.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../App1.css'
import CanvasJSReact from '../assets/canvasjs.react';
var CanvasJSChart = CanvasJSReact.CanvasJSChart;


var dataPoints =[];
var dataPoints_1 = [];
var dataPoints_2 = [];


class LineChart extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            results: []
        };
    }

.
.
.
.
componentDidMount(){
        var chart = this.chart;
        var chart1 = this.chart1;
        var chart2 = this.chart2;
        fetch('http://localhost:4000/espdata/')
        .then((response) => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then((ResData) => {
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                var today = new Date(ResData.dados[i].Time);
                dataPoints.push({
                    x: today,
                    y: ResData.dados[i].T_air
                });
                dataPoints_1.push({
                    x: today,
                    y: ResData.dados[i].H_air
                });
                dataPoints_2.push({
                    x: today,
                    y: ResData.dados[i].soil
                });
            }
            chart.render();
            chart1.render();
            chart2.render();
            this.setState({results: ResData.LastTime});
            console.log(this.results);   //UNDEFINED
            console.log(ResData.LastTime) // "12/12/2019, 15:43:53"
        });
    }
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: It's normal this.results is undefined, this would be this.state.results. However, you can't access state directly after you've set it.

Comment: setState is async function

Comment: What @Axnyff says is correct. Change it to use this.state.results and you will get an empty array instead of undefined. setState is asynchronous, so you can't access the results you want immediately.

Comment: 1. You have to access results by `this.state.results`. Because we are setting results property inside the state object.
2. Basically setState is asynchronous, so if you try print in the next line it will return previous value(If no value initiated, then it will be undefined). So use callback function for further operation. It is very similar to Promise.

Comment: @Axnyff thanks a lot it worked. I did <h1>{this.state.results}</h1> and it prints now the time! I feel dumb by not realising I had to use this.state. Thx a lot

Comment: Another popular duplicate target: [Why calling react setState method doesn't mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30782948/1218980)

Comment: @Srigar Used the arrow function to console.log and worked. Now I understood better. Cheers mate

Answer (score -2):

SetState is A Promise, if you need to use it immediately after setting it, you 
 should use it as a promise, like this:

```
this.setState({results: ResData.LastTime}, () => {console.log(this.state. results); })
```

Comment: No, it is not a promise.

Comment: That's not a promise, is it? It's asynchronous, but it doesn't return a Promise or a 'thennable'

Comment: Yes exactly, sorry I was wrong, it's not a Promise, it's just an asynchronous function.

Comment: It worked. I was missing the this.state and understood the fact that setState is Async. Thx